# How to access a variable from an object in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c

How to access a variable from an Object in Objective-C. ie if i have a variable of say:

```
(NSString*) string;
```

How do i access this through an object?

Comment: this question doesn't make sense. What is that code supposed to be? An instance variable declaration? Why are there parentheses?

Answer (score 0):

Directly by dot notation

```
obj.myString = str
str = obj.myString
```

Implement your own getter and setter

```
[obj setMyString: str]
[obj myString]
```

Have the compiler implement getter and setter by @property/@synchronized

```
[obj setMyString: str]
[obj myString]
```

All methods are covered in the [Properties in Objective-C 2.0](http://www.cocoacast.com/?q=node/103) Cocoa Cast.

Comment: `[obj setMyString:something];`

Answer (score 0):

Use the .(dot) **classobj.string** notation or use **[classobj string]** where string is the Nsstring placed in object class **(Obj *classobj instance)**